# How to attach a file in body of email using spring integration

Tags: spring, email, integration, jakarta-mail

I have a situation where I need to attached file in the body of the email rather than in the header. For example in Microsoft outlook if message type set to Rich Text one can drag and drop file in the body of email as an attachment. How do I do that using Spring Integration MessageBuilder?? so far this is I am using to send attachment but file attached to email in header not in body.

```
Message<?> msg = MessageBuilder.withPayload("")
.setHeader(MailHeaders.SUBJECT, subject )
.setHeader(MailHeaders.ATTACHMENT_FILENAME, args[0].toString())
.build();
```

If someone give me code example would be great help! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Your code shows you're ignoring a key piece of the message itself, the `payload`

1. Wire your outbound message adapter with the `JavaMailSender` (as you probably already have)
2. Construct a regular `MimeMessage` using the `org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender` you wired and `org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper`,  as in

   ```
    public void sendEmail(){
    MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage(); //mailSender is an instance of             JavaMailSender from 1.
   try{
   MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,true);
   //set the fields
   helper.setFrom("J'onn Doe");
   helper.setTo("SpamRecce");
   helper.setSubject("")
   helper.setText("Text goes here")
   //load attachment file using spring's help. Basic interface is called a Resource and there       are many implementations. Here, I've used the ClassPathResource which means your attachment file must be in your classpath
   ClassPathResource theAttachment = new ClassPathResource("My File.Doc");
   helper.addAttachment("Add the desired filename here.doc",theAttachment);
       }
   catch(MessagingException me){
   Logger.getAnonymousLogger.info("Something bad happened!);
   me.printStacktrace();
        }
   mailSender.send(message);
    }
   ```

I don't know your implementation details but I believe the endpoint that sends the email should be a terminating endpoint i.e., the email can be sent directly from that endpoint, you shouldn't need to send onto another channel.

If however, you still need to flush the message on to another channel, you need to rewrite the code you have there to read:

```
     Message<MimeMessage> msg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(message)
          .setHeader(MailHeaders.SUBJECT, subject )
          .setHeader(MailHeaders.ATTACHMENT_FILENAME, args[0].toString())
          .build();
```